# Basic Python OpenCV cropping and resizing

Tags: python, opencv, math

can someone help me with a little cropping algorithm? its openCV.. im trying to figure this out. I know the method is crop = image[y:y1, x:x1].
If I have an image with new_dimensionXxnew_dimensionY pixels and I want to crop it to the same width but the height just above 121px above pointOfInterestX. How can I do that?

One more question:

```
image = cv2.resize(image,(int(new_dimensionX), int(new_dimensionY)))
cv2.imwrite("test6.jpg", image)
```

The file test6.jpg does not reflect the resize done in the line just above it. Why?

Answer (score 7):

When you show the resized image with **imshow()** it shows the image on-screen and change showing window size according to an image pixel. when you open the image with image viewer it open image in fixed window size and window size don't depend on image pixel

OpenCV provides a function called resize to achieve image scaling. Two way to scale an image

1. By providing required size
2. By giving scaling factor

If you don't specify a size (by using None), then it expects the X and Y scaling factors

while providing **scaling size**

```
import cv2
filename = "path_to_image"

oriimage = cv2.imread(filename)

print oriimage.shape
newx,newy = oriimage.shape[1]/4,oriimage.shape[0]/4 #new size (w,h)

newimage = cv2.resize(oriimage,(newx,newy))

print newimage.shape

cv2.imshow("original image",oriimage)
cv2.imshow("resize image",newimage)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

with **scaling ratio**

```
import cv2
filename = "path_to_image"

image = cv2.imread(filename) 

small = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5) 

large = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=1.5, fy=1.5)

cv2.imshow("small image",small)
cv2.imshow("large image",large)

#To save rescale image
cv2.imwrite('s.jpg',small)
cv2.imwrite('l.jpg',large)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

For detail parameter of **[resize()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#cv2.resize)** method

**Crop image in** **opencv**

```
import cv2
im_path = "path/to/image"
img = cv2.imread(im_path)

crop_img = img[0:400, 0:300] # Crop from {x, y, w, h } => {0, 0, 300, 400}

cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Opencv imread method read image and return numpy array, and Size of numpy array equal to image array.If you want to crop image just select an array

```
img[0:400,0:300]
```

**Note** : its img[y: y + h, x: x + w]   img take first y and height second is x and width

Comment: Why does imwrite not note the changes of the resize done that imshow displays?

Comment: @DavidKachlon Check my updated answer, In 2 example I save rescaled image. After executing program compare pixel size of all images, all images pixel size different.

Comment: image = cv2.resize(image,(int(new_dimensionX), int(new_dimensionY)))
crop_img = image[int(pointOfInterestX-121):int(new_dimensionY), 0:int(new_dimensionX-(pointOfInterestX+121))]
cv2.imshow("Faces found", crop_img)
cv2.imwrite("cropped.jpg", crop_img) 


line 4 does not reflect the changes made in line 1, but line 3 does. why?

Comment: @DavidKachlon In line 1 you just resize the image with new_dimensionX and new_dimensionY, it's working. you have to check the pixel of saved image it should equal to resize the image. When you show the image it shows the image on-screen and change showing window size according to an image pixel. when you open the image with image viewer it open image in fixed window size and window size don't depend on image pixel

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
im_path = "path/to/image"
img = cv2.imread(im_path)

crop_img = img[0:400, 0:300] # Crop from {x, y, w, h } => {0, 0, 300, 400}

cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**